# Is "that's two words" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is "that's two words" grammatically correct?

Or should it be "those are two words"?

I think the second example using "those" is correct since it refers to the word in its plural form.

I could only find examples on the internet where people write "that's two words", and I am not sure if that is right.

Comment: It is valid, in the proper context.

Comment: That (statement) is two words (long).

Comment: The context should be when analysing two words.. like: "self defence" or "common sense"

Comment: There are people here who would argue that open compounds each  constitute a single word. Leaving aside that issue: as Nigel suggests, there is notional agreement in " 'Common sense' for a single-word answer? That's two words." ie " ... That answer / suggestion / expression ... comprises/involves two [orthographic] words." Notional agreement is still something of a grey area, so one could estimate this as being say 80% acceptable. "Those are two words" here would perhaps be only 75% acceptable on non-idiomaticity grounds.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's expand the contraction to clearly show the subject and the verb:

**That is two words.**

"**That**"--demonstrative pronoun (singular) [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That ]

"**is**"--a linking verb (singular; NOT an action verb).

**When a linking verb is used**

"A linking verb ("is," "are," "was," "were," "seem" and others) agrees with its subject, not its complement."

[ https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/grammarpunct/subjectverb/ ]

"**words**"--subject complement (quantified by "**two**"--numeral determiner)

"A subject complement follows a linking verb; it is normally an adjective or a noun that renames or defines in some way the subject."

[http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm ]

Based on that, I don't think it would've mattered if there were 1000 words, as long as "that" referred to something singular, such as an essay...or, another example, a Stephen King novel: I read *Duma Key*. That's 609 pages!

The last page is two sentences:

*Know when you're finished, and when you are, put your pencil or your paintbrush down. All the rest is only life.*

(Which reminds me, something singular, as I put it, may be a mass noun, not necessarily a countable noun, if I'm not mistaken...but I'm finished now.)