# Is the phrase "it is people like you" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My friend and I had an argument whether the usage of the phrase, "It is people like you that..." was correct. I insisted that since the subject was people, a plural, the corresponding verb could not be singular - is. His argument was that 'people like you' should treated as a group. Please advise.

Comment: 'Is' is a linking verb connecting to the subject 'it'. See, eg, https://english.stackexchange.com/a/448605/42179.

Comment: The dummy pronoun "it" is subject, not people".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It is people like you* [*who cause problems*].

This is an *it*-cleft construction where the subject is not "people", but the dummy pronoun "it".

The noun phrase "people like you" functions as predicative complement of "is". Singular PCs are also possible as in *It is Sue who likes you*.

The bracketed element is a non-modifying relative clause, with *people like you* as antecedent of "who".

Answer (score -1):

The comment is correct and precise.

The usage is most often to disparage "Those people" as a group. Making such generalizations of folks is a lazy means of pigeon-holing them so as to ignore their opinions or concerns. I do my best not to be one of those people.